# Firestore Cross origin request blocked

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a react js chat app. I want to list the sub collections of document in fire store from front end react. On internet few people said it's not possible to access the list of sub collection through front end. And some how I came to find out the following code which uses the httpsCallable() to access the list of sub collections from this [source](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) here

```
const getSubCollections = firebase
      .functions()
      .httpsCallable("getSubCollections");
      
    getSubCollections({ docPath: "users/JOtnZTNsc1dRUvmohgO7tNCotsk2" })
      .then(function (result) {
        var collections = result.data.collections;
        console.log(collections);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Getting the Error details.
        var code = error.code;
        var message = error.message;
        var details = error.details;
        // ...
      });
```

When I'm running this it's saying cross origin request blocked. How can I resolve this.

Or else is there any other way to list all the sub collections inside of a document in the firestore using the front end of react js only.

Comment: "When I'm running this it's saying cross origin request blocked." => How do you "run" it? (In other words, how do you call this callable Cloud Function)? Also, you say "And some how I came to find out the following code which uses the httpsCallable() to access the list of sub collections" => Can you point out the origin of this code? In particular, how is the `getSubCollections` inner function defined?

Comment: Kindly check the source I have modified it in the question it self.

Comment: Thanks for having updated the question. Actually I wrote the article you refer to :-). And actually my comment above is erroneous: In my comment I mixed up the code of the Callable Cloud Function and the code of the front-end calling the Cloud Function… Can you double check that you have implemented the two parts according to the article? Do you see the Cloud Function in the Firebase console?

Comment: OMG! feeling thankful for your article and replies especially.
I have used the 2nd approach of that article and written only the 2nd code as you gave for the java script SDK. Cause you used the identifier "export" where I haven't found anything that's related to it. And it's causing the issue, if I write it.
Another thing is as you have said " Calling this Cloud Function from the client is even easier ", I  have gone through it and thought it gonna work.
But I don't that I gonna end up with the errors, cause I'm a beginner to this firestore and reactjs.

Comment: For the second approach you need to deploy the Cloud Function and then you can call it from your front-end. I would kindly suggest that you first look at the doc on Cloud Function https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions. Then you implement the code in the article and everything should work correctly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Creating this answer as a community wiki, as it's based on the comments and the article provided by @RenaudTarnec.

For the Cloud Function approach, you actually have to deploy a function with the implementation of the code described in the article before being able to call it from your front-end. You can find more information on how to do this in the [Cloud Functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).